# Upload a HttpPostedFileBase for image but always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and web programming.

My uploading image is working fine, but when I use almost the exact same code to allow user to modify its upload, it HttpPostedFileBase is always null. Driving me crazy...

here is the model
     public class ModifyGenreViewModel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

```
        [Display(Name = "Nom du style")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ModifyGenre", "Upload", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-horizontal">

                <h4>@Resource.StyleCreationHeader</h4>

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>Model)
                <div class="form-group" style="display:none">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" data-val="true" id="ModifyGenreViewModel_Image" name="ModifyGenreViewModel.Image" />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="@Resource.Modify" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

When I set the breakpoint in my controller, I see the Id and the name, but Image is always null.

Thank's for your help!

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { type = "file" })` will generate the correct html

Answer (score 2):

The name property value of your file input should match with the view model property name for model binding to work properly.

Change the input field name to `"Image"`

```
<input type="file" data-val="true" id="ModifyGenreViewModel_Image" name="Image" />
```

Assuming your HttpPost action method accepts the `ModifyGenreViewModel` object as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyGenre(ModifyGenreViewModel  model)
{
  // to do : return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In model class change it to **public String Image { get; set; }**
2. In .cshtml page change it to **@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new {
   type = "file", name="Image" })**
3. In Controller you should use the name what you have decleared in html    helper *HttpPostedFileBase **Image***